# How to remove installed packages by daily PPA

Tags: ubuntu, ppa

On elementary OS I accidentally added the daily ppa and updated the machine on a daily basis.

Now i want to remove all the apps that are installed by this ppa. How to do that?

Can i do this automatically or do i have to search for all installed packages and remove/downgrade them one by one?

I already removed the PPA from sources.list.d/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install a small app called ppa-purge. It will uninstall/downgrade all the apps & libraries installed.

To install ppa-purge,  open a terminal and:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
```

To more info, visit the manpage

[ppa-purge](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/ppa-purge.1.html)

Comment: Zerco,  if the answer solved your ask, you can upvote it, in order to help others.